# Set the newsticker group hierarchy in the init file

Tags: newsticker

I've read on how to add each feed using the variable `newsticker-url-list`. I did something like this in the init file and it works.

```el
(setq newsticker-url-list '(
  ("stackoverflow.com - emacs" "https://stackoverflow.com/feeds/tag?tagnames=emacs&sort=newest" nil nil nil)
  ("archlinux news" "https://www.archlinux.org/feeds/news/" nil nil nil)
  ("archlinux packages" "https://www.archlinux.org/feeds/packages/" nil nil nil)))
```

But how do you create groups/subgroups and assign these feeds to the created groups/subgroups? I've read on how to do this interactively, But how do you do all this within the init file (non-interactively)?

Comment: Is "newsticker" an emacs package? Is it in ELPA/MELPA? Is there a website?

Comment: It used to be a seperate package. Now it's part of emacs. https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_mono/newsticker.html

Comment: Thank you - added the tag and submitted an edit to it (which will not be visible until it is reviewed).

Answer (score 1):

You can set the variable `newsticker-groups` (see `C-h v newsticker-groups`), or edit the file `{newsticker-dir}/groups`, where `newsticker-dir` is the value of the variable `newsticker-dir` (defaults to the 'newsticker' subdirectory of your emacs config directory).

Answer (score 0):

There are 2 variables at play:  `newsticker-url-list` and `newsticker-groups`.

##### newsticker-url-list

This is a flat list where each item represents a feed.  The format of the items inside this list is:

```lisp
(LABEL URL START-TIME INTERVAL WGET-ARGUMENTS)
```

The last 3 are often `nil`.

##### newsticker-groups

This controls how the list from `newsticker-url-list` is displayed, and it can introduce hierarchy if you want.  Its structure is:

```lisp
(GROUP-LABEL ITEM1 ITEM2 ITEM3 ...)
```

The `GROUP-LABEL` can be an arbitrary string, but the items should refer back to labels that were declared previously in `newsticker-url-list`.  The items may also be another group structure, and they may be nested arbitrarily deep.

##### Example

```lisp
(setq newsticker-url-list
      '(("Bisq Releases" "https://github.com/bisq-network/bisq/releases.atom" nil nil nil)
        ("Electrum Tags" "https://github.com/spesmilo/electrum/tags.atom" nil nil nil)
        ("Clojure Releases" "https://clojure.org/feed.xml" nil nil nil)
        ("Node.js Releases" "https://nodejs.org/en/feed/releases.xml" nil nil nil)
        ("Photography" "https://nitter.net/i/lists/1388207152825737216/rss" nil nil nil)
        ("Design/Architecture" "https://nitter.net/i/lists/925139890685087744" nil nil nil)
        ("Illustrators" "https://nitter.net/i/lists/1476654089027010567" nil nil nil)))
(setq newsticker-groups
      '("Feeds"
        ("Software"
         "Bisq Releases"
         "Electrum Tags"
         "Clojure Releases"
         "Node.js Releases")
        ("Twitter"
         "Design/Architecture"
         "Illustrators")))
```